# I couldn't enable auditing in sharepoint 3.0

Tags: sharepoint

I have a test sharepoint site with version 12.0.0.6219. I wanted to enable auditing feature, but I couldn't find a link or menu to enable it.

There is no Configure Audit Settings for site even particular document library. I couldn't view the Audit Log Reports either.

So, where I can enable auditing in sharepoint 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use WSS 3 then auditing is not included, you need a third party product [such as this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit/summary.aspx) (disclaimer, I worked on it).

If you have MOSS 2007 then it is included.

Answer (score 2):

@Muhimbi - that is not completelty true.

Auditing is included in WSS 3.  There is no web UI to access the settings like in MOSS 2007.  The auditing functions are accessible via the programming model.  You need to create custom components that enable and view the audit information or purchase a third party product that does the same thing.